# Timing for Rum infusions

Tags: rum

Since the quarantines and lockdowns, I have picked up the hobby of infusing alcohol. Various sources give various advice as to the length of time in which to let a "Rhum Arrangè" set... some say 2 days, some say 2 weeks, some say 2 months. The basic tenet being 'when it tastes good to you, it's ready.'

I also understand that the higher the proof, the faster and more efficient the dispersal of the flavors...

My question has to do specifically with tea infused rum - I recently bottled some [genmaicha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genmaicha) in white rum with a couple spoons of honey and a dash of lemon. Realizing that tea will infuse in water in just a few minutes, I am worried that letting it sit for more than just a week or so could make the rum too bitter... Does anyone have some experience with this? How long should I let it sit, accordingly?

Answer (score 3):

It will vary based on the quantity of tea as well, but a day or two should be plenty. I have not done tea in rum but I did 4 teabags of Lapsang Souchong in a bottle of bourbon, and that only took a day or two.

You can always infuse for longer if you need to, I would recommend tasting after 24 hours.

Comment: Yes, I see... as an update, I removed the tea after about 10 days and I think I waited too long. The rum is good but the tea flavor is VERY strong.